# My android app doesn't connect to the server throw android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to launch a connection (by a regular socket programming approaches) between my android app and a server but when running my app with eclipse through android emulator it doesn't connect, I separated the connection code in a java regular project to make sure that it works and everything going great.

**The Logcat:**

```
12-25 16:43:51.019: W/System.err(590):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-25 16:43:51.019: W/System.err(590):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-25 16:43:51.019: W/System.err(590):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-25 16:43:51.029: W/System.err(590):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-25 16:43:51.029: W/System.err(590):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 16:43:51.029: W/System.err(590):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 16:43:51.049: W/System.err(590): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-25 16:43:51.062: W/System.err(590):  at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
12-25 16:43:51.069: W/System.err(590):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:169)
12-25 16:43:51.069: W/System.err(590):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
12-25 16:43:51.069: W/System.err(590):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: Is it local server. Can you include the server endpoint?

Comment: it's a local server which i connect through wifi, i connect to it using it's ip and a port num

Comment: Be more specific. Can you please give the port and the ip?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev 192.168.30.7   7778

Comment: Ok it is not what I suspected... What happens when you try to connect? Is it IOException? Do you have access internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev i added the logcat to the question, and what's the  access internet permission at the manifest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43905/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-mrefaat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the particular question permission was missing in the Android Manifest file. Add the following line in our manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And you will be one step closer to getting the things work!